# In Razor view how do you build a lookup for a text box?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an MVC4 application using razor view engine.  On an edit page I have a text box that contains a value which the user would select from a list (stored in another table).  For example lets say we have an edit page for customers and in addition to the customer table we have another table called customer types.

I want to add a button on the edit page for the customer that would be next to the customer type field but would open a modal window with a sortable grid that I could select a specificy customer type from the customer type table. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Could you put your controller and view code?

Comment: I've experimented with Zurb Foundation and they have a built in Modal feature.  I have been able to click a button that opens a modal form on top of my page.  But I'm not sure how to put a grid on this form that I can show my list on so that the user can select one from the list.